# how can I use less dynamically

Tags: css, less

I have a bootstrap button on my html page:

```
<button type='button' class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='.navbar-collapse'>
```

a bit further down I have this:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
```

when I hover over my button the background-color changes to the value that I expect using this selector:

```
.navbar-header > .navbar-toggle:hover {
background-color: #9c83bb;
color: #fff;
}
```

When I click my button the target div changes to:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse on">
```

So using Less I want to be able to keep the color of the hover background while 'on' is attached to the target div.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, don't you just need `&.on{ background-color: #9c83bb; }` in the `.navbar-collapse` style?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use .navbar-toggle:focus ?

Comment: @DBS I added ` .navbar-collapse &.on {
        background-color: #9c83bb;
    }` to my stylesheet, but it made no difference

Comment: @MikeRodham No I don't think I do want `focus` since the mouse may not be on the button. When the target has `on` attached by bootstrap, the menu items below the parent are displayed. I may not have my mouse over the original `navbar-toggle` class, and it may still not have the focus, it may be a menuitem that has the focus, but while `on` is attached to the target I want my background to stay

Answer (score 0):

Less is just a preprocessor, it's not going to provide you with the ability to go back to a previous element and change its classes or styling depending on the existence of a class on a separate element lower in the DOM. If you want to do that, you're going to need JavaScript.

A different way to do this would be to alter the elements completely independent of eachother, but still provide both of them with a toggleable state. More specifically: change the button into a checkbox, hide the checkbox, and style the label. You can still have the data attributes `data-toggle` and `data-target` on your element, it will just be a different type of element.

```css
input.navbar-toggle ~ label:hover {
  background-color: #9c83bb;
  color: #fff;
}

input.navbar-toggle {
  display: none;
}

input.navbar-toggle ~ label {
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 2px;
 border-radius: 3px;
}

input.navbar-toggle:checked ~ label {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #9c83bb;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input type='checkbox' id="navbar-toggle-input" class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='.navbar-collapse' /><label for="navbar-toggle-input">Toggle</label>

<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">Navbar!<div>
```

---

#### **Edit:**

If you wanted to do the same thing with JavaScript:

```js
document.getElementById('navbar-toggle-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var target = this.dataset.target.replace('.', '');
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName(target)[0] // This is lazy, don't do this. It's just for testing

  if (hasClass(element, 'show')) {
    this.style.color = 'white';
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  } else {
    this.style.color = '#fff';
    this.style.backgroundColor = '#9c83bb';
  }
});

function hasClass(target, className) {
  return new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)').test(target.className);
}
```

```css
button.navbar-toggle:hover {
  background-color: #9c83bb;
  color: #fff;
}

button.navbar-toggle {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type='button' id="navbar-toggle-button" class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='.navbar-collapse'>Toggle</button>

<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">Navbar!<div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've gone with the checkbox method and a label, however I cannot seem to get my icon-bar spans to display now. I have the following `<label for="navbar-toggle-input">
                    <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                </label>`